# Angular Autentication Service using Owin and Identity and JWT

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, jwt

I'm bulding a web api with owin and JWT, when I execute the project it shows me an exception. This is a method that consume the JWT, I'm having problems with `as:AudienceId` and `as:AudienceSecret`, it tells me that AudienceSecret is null. What can be the issue?

```
private void ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        var issuer = "http://localhost:59822";
        string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
        byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

        // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: I guess you should show the code for your `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is looking for the appSettings key **as:AudienceSecret** in *web.config* file.

```
    byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);
```

Since the result *audienceSecret* is null.  The statement is not finding the key **as:AudienceSecret**.  The most reasonable explanation is the key is missing from *web.config*.  You need to add the key to *web.config* like this.Something like this

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="as:AudienceId" value="414e1927a3884f68abc79f7283837fd1" />
    <add key="as:AudienceSecret" value="qMCdFDQuF23RV1Y-1Gq9L3cF3VmuFwVbam4fMTdAfpo" />
  </appSettings>
```

You may want to use different values cause it's ... a secret.